# Perform an aggregation on JSON data in JavaScript. I have to get the total number of Records for each school and total Marks of School Records

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have input data in the Below format:

```
{
 "data": {
  "listStudents": {
   "items": [
    {
     "Marks": 5,
     "Grade": "Grade6",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria School",
     "SkillsetName": "Reading",
     "StudentName": "Abdur Rahman"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 5,
     "Grade": "Grade6",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria School",
     "SkillsetName": "Numeracy",
     "StudentName": "Munazza Maryam"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 3,
     "Grade": "Grade3",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria School",
     "SkillsetName": "Numeracy",
     "StudentName": "Y. Divya sri"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 4,
     "Grade": "Grade4",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria High School",
     "SkillsetName": "Reading",
     "StudentName": "Syed Soheb Ahmed"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 2,
     "Grade": "Grade3",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria High School",
     "SkillsetName": "Numeracy",
     "StudentName": "Mohammed Hanzala Sharieff"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 3,
     "Grade": "Grade5",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria High School",
     "SkillsetName": "Numeracy",
     "StudentName": "Syed Sulaiman"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 5,
     "Grade": "Grade6",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria High",
     "SkillsetName": "Reading",
     "StudentName": "Mohammed Shariq"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 2,
     "Grade": "Grade6",
     "SchoolName": "Sri Siddhartha High",
     "SkillsetName": "Reading",
     "StudentName": "SUMASRI"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 3,
     "Grade": "Grade4",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria High",
     "SkillsetName": "Reading",
     "StudentName": "Huda Anjum"
    },
    {
     "Marks": 5,
     "Grade": "Grade4",
     "SchoolName": "New St. Maria High",
     "SkillsetName": "Reading",
     "StudentName": "Nuzhath Ruqhaiya"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I have to perform an Aggregation in Javascript to get the output as below:

```
{list: 
[{
SchoolName: New St. Maria High,
TotalMarks:13,
TotalCount:3
},
{
SchoolName: Sri Siddhartha High,
TotalMarks:2,
TotalCount:1
},
{
SchoolName: New St. Maria High School,
TotalMarks:9,
TotalCount:3
},
{
SchoolName: New St. Maria High,
TotalMarks:10,
TotalCount:3
}]
}
```

Below is the logic that I Have written:

```
    const uniqueTags = [];
    var SchoolName = null;
    var Sum = 0;
    Object.values(result.data.listStudents.items).forEach((x) => {
      if (SchoolName === x.SchoolName) {
        Sum = Sum + x.Marks;
        SchoolName = x.SchoolName;
      } else if (SchoolName === null) {
        Sum = x.Marks;
        SchoolName = x.SchoolName;
      } else if (SchoolName != x.SchoolName) {
        uniqueTags.push(Sum, SchoolName);
        SchoolName = x.SchoolName;
        Sum = x.Marks;
      }
    });

    console.log(uniqueTags);
```

But I am not getting any output of the code. Can I get some help to get it working as per the requirement?
I tried the map function too but I am not able to get it working by any means. Any kind of help is appreciated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the logic in 2 parts then it will be easy for you to implement. -

```
let tempResult = [];

Object.values(result.data.listStudents.items).forEach((x) => {
    if (!tempResult.hasOwnProperty(x.SchoolName)) {
        tempResult[x.SchoolName] = {TotalMarks: 0, TotalCount: 0} ;
    }

    tempResult[x.SchoolName].TotalMarks = tempResult[x.SchoolName].TotalMarks + x.Marks;
    tempResult[x.SchoolName].TotalCount = tempResult[x.SchoolName].TotalCount + 1;
});

let listRec = [];
let i = 0;
Object.keys(tempResult).forEach(function (k) {
    listRec[i++] = { SchoolName: k, TotalMarks: tempResult[k].TotalMarks, TotalCount: tempResult[k].TotalCount };
});

let finalResult = { list: listRec };
console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: thank you, @Amit Gupta. I am getting the desired output. Can you correct me if my understanding is wrong anywhere?
1. We are running a loop using for each and 
2, then checking whether each record has the matching school name or not. 
3. If does not have the same school name then resetting the total Marks and total Count. Else continue adding them. 
O/P :: SchoolName: { TotalMarks, TotalCount}

Then in the second part, we are running a loop on the tempResult that we got in the previous section and writing it as a list but this time writing the index value as SchoolName

Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, In first loop we are creating a JSON array with SchoolName as key and storing TotalMarks and TotalCount. In first loop it first check if SchoolName is exist or not, if not then create it else keep adding Marks and Count in that School key. And in second loop we are looping through all keys and creating the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the Array.prototype.reduce-function like this:

```
let aggregatedData = jsonData.data.listStudents.items.reduce((prev,curr) => {
    const agg = prev.list.find((s) => s.SchoolName == curr.SchoolName);
    if(!agg){
        prev.list.push({SchoolName: curr.SchoolName, TotalMarks: curr.Marks, TotalCount: 1});
    } else {
        agg.TotalMarks += curr.Marks;
        agg.TotalCount++;
    }
    return prev;

}, {list: []});
```

I hope this solves yout problem!

Comment: Thank you Very much. The logic gives the Answer in the expected format. Will it be possible for you to explain a little about what exactly we are doing in the Snippet. I am not able to follow it through. Especially this section:

const agg = prev.list.find((s) => s.SchoolName == curr.SchoolName);

Comment: The reduce-function is one of the handiest and most useful funcions for Arrays in JS. It can be used to aggregate the content of an Array to ajy desired form. It's also easier to follow and often faster than doing seperate for-loops. This said the find-function can be used to get the first element of an array that corresponds to the rule. In this example I checked, if the result-Array already contains an element for this school. If not, it returns undefied. If yes, I can increment the marks and counter.

Comment: Also just a short advice: try to use conventions for variable-naming. For example i would recommend to start all variables in this JSON file with a lower-case letter and then use the camel-case notation (e.g. schoolName). Usually Expressions that start with an upper-case letter are class names.

Comment: Thank you @user16192538. 
That really helps as I am from data warehousing background and totally new to coding conventions.
I will change the variables and JSON names accordingly.